# How to test in SAPUI5 with OPA5 if a dialog is successfully closed? (Negative testing)

Tags: sapui5, integration-testing

I wonder how to test with OPA5 if a Dialog is successfully closed after pressing the corresponding button.

This is how I test if the dialog is open:

```js
{
  // ...
  iShouldSeeTheSortDialog: function () {
    return this.waitFor({
      controlType: "sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog",
      id: "sortDialog",
      fragmentId: "sortFragment",
      success: function () {
        Opa5.assert.ok(true, "The sort dialog is open");
      },
      errorMessage: "Did not find the sort dialog control"
    });
  },
}
```

Now I'm looking for the exact opposite test case. I would like to search for the `sortDialog` and throw a success if it is not found anymore.
Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: More or less related sidenote. We tested opa, uiver5 and wdio. We switched all tests to wdio it's the fastest most flexible and stable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

If you want to check if a dialog has been closed but not destroyed, you can do it this way:

```js
{
    //..
    iShouldNotSeeDialog: function () {
        return this.waitFor({
            id: "dialogID",
            visible: false,
            success: function (oDialog) {
                Opa5.assert.notOk(oDialog.getVisible(), "Dialog is not visible -- OK");
            },
            errorMessage: "Checking Field: dialogID -- Assertion Failed"
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to check if a dialog has been destroyed, you can do this as follows:

```js
{
    //..
    iShouldNotSeeDialog: function () {
        return this.waitFor({
            success: function () {
                var bExists = (Opa5.getJQuery()("#" + "dialogID").length > 0);
                Opa5.assert.notOk(bExists, "Dialog doesn't exist -- OK");
            },
            errorMessage: "-- Assertion Failed"
        });
    }
}
```